# Searching two of the three characters in python

Tags: python, python-3.4

```
 info=('x','y','z')
 info2=('x','Bob','y')
 match=False
 if any(all x in info for x in info2):
    match=True
    print("True")
 else:
     print("False")
```

Is that is there a way I can make it work so that it only prints `True` when `x` and either `y` or `z` are in `info2`?

Comment: Please clarify your question. For example, would `'x' in info2 and ('y' in info2 or 'z' in info1)` work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I read this you want the first element in `info` (`info[0]`), and at least one other element in `info` to be in `info2`

```
 if info[0] in info2 and any(i in info2 for i in info[1:]):
     # do stuff
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what i wanted